# Microsoft Edge Websockets: "SCRIPT12030" error after 30secs

Tags: javascript, angular, websocket, microsoft-edge

I am developing an Angular 5 Application, which talks to the Server (IoT Device) over a Websocket connection, where JSON-messages are sent and also received.

The application works fine on Firefox, Chrome and Opera - but with Microsoft Edge, the connection closes after an idle time of 30sec with the following error message:

`SCRIPT12030: WebSocket Error: Network Error 12030, The connection with the server was terminated abnormally`

Additional information:

- IoT-Device is in LAN, so no Proxy is used
- Connection closes after 30sec of inactivity on the websocket connection
- There is no difference, if i use "ws://" or "wss://"
- The other parts of the Angular applications work normal
- Version of Edge is 40.15063.674.0, EdgeHTML 15.15063

How can i keep the connection open?

Comment: It seems, that Edge sends Pong Messages to the server, but the server doesn't respond to them and so Edge closes the connection. The server also doesn't send Ping-Messages -> so Pong would not be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Edge sends "Pong"-messages - even if their was no "Ping"-Message before.

The IoT-Device could not parse the "Pong"-message and closed the websocket connection.

Other browser only respond with "Pong"-messages, if their was a "Ping"-message before. As solution we implemented Ping/Pong-in our IoT-Device.